# Why does uniq return original value of array after map in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I tried the following code:

```
numbers = [1,2,2,3,4]
numbers.map.uniq {|number| number < 2 }
```

My understanding is that the return value of `map` is passed to `uniq`. I expected:

```
[true, false]
```

Instead, I received:

```
[1, 2]
```

It seems that `uniq` maintains a reference to the original array.

Could someone provide insight into this behaviour?

Comment: Great question. These are always such tough things to figure out in languages and have such satisfying "ah ha!" moments when you figure out what's happening :)

Comment: To get the expected result use `numbers.map {|number| number < 2 }.uniq`

Comment: What is `p` in the block doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) accepts a block, defining *the condition on what should be treated `uniq`*.

```
main > numbers = [1,2,2,3,4].map
#⇒ #<Enumerator: ...>
main > numbers.uniq
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]

# effectively the same as
main > numbers.to_a.uniq
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]

main > numbers.uniq { |number| number.odd? }
#⇒ [1, 2]
```

The latter returns one odd and one non-odd (even) element. In your case it returns 1 element that is less than 2 and one element that is greater or equal to two.

---

Note, that `map` enumerator is effectively there:

```
numbers.each &Math.method(:sqrt)
#⇒ [1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951,
#        1.7320508075688772, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually doing anything with the map call, your function is roughly equivalent to this:

```
[1,2,2,3,4].uniq {|number| p number < 2 }
```

Methods like `map` return an `Enumerable` type, and you are then calling `uniq` on that `Enumerable`. From the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

> If no block is given, an Enumerator is returned instead.

Effectively your map is a no-op.

I think you're also misunderstanding the `uniq` method. `Uniq` is going to filter out any elements from an array that aren't unique (eg: `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5].uniq == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`), not return whether the element is unique (true or false) in the array.

Comment: The true/false would come from the map. I do understand what uniq returns. I am not understanding why if I swap `uniq` and `map` why uniq will do it's thing and pass the result forward to map but the opposite is not true.

Comment: [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) returns an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) **instance**, not an `Enumerable`. This is usually a result of call to [`Object#enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-enum_for): `def my_each; return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?; ... end`.

Answer (score -1):

```rb
numbers.uniq.map { |number| number < 2 }
```

### uniq method

> uniq → new_ary click to toggle source uniq {|item| ...} → new_ary
>   Returns a new array by removing duplicate values in self.
>
> If a block is given, it will use the return value of the block for
>   comparison.
>   It compares values using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.
>   self is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept.
>
> a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
>
> a.uniq   # => ["a", "b", "c"]
>
> b = [["student","sam"], ["student","george"], ["teacher","matz"]]
>
> b.uniq {|s| s.first}   # => [["student", "sam"], ["teacher", "matz"]]

You can read more about uniq method [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Comment: Maybe add a little context to this answer. You are not wrong, although the result will differ for the proposed intention, you have just not explained anything right now. Remember this is a teachable moment for the OP so offer some insight

Comment: This makes me wonder why uniq can be pass forward values but map will not?

Comment: @JustinDuncan Please, read documentation for uniq method https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq
```ruby
numbers.map.uniq {|number| p number < 2 }
```
equivalent to
```ruby
numbers.uniq {|number| p number < 2 }
```

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin you got there first